Flask - Server returns 404 even though view function is called
I am writing simple Flask app that uses the Facebook/Bart model from Hugging Face for summarizing text. In this project I try to set up the authentication in the http-only cookies format. Here are my code:
config.py
import os
import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv

#load environment variable
load_dotenv()

#configure the app object before running it
class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL_AWS') 
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False 
    JWT_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('JWT_SECRET_KEY')
    JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = 'cookies'
    JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
    JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = datetime.timedelta(hours=1) #expire after 1 hour
    DEBUG = True

app.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, create_access_token, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity, set_access_cookies, unset_access_cookies
from flask_cors import CORS
from model.models import db, User, Notes
from config.config import Config
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from api.summary_model import summarize_text

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app=app)
CORS(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

#!authentication route
@app.route("/register", methods = ['POST'])
def register():
        print("Register function called")
    data = request.json
    if not data:
        app.logger.error("No JSON data received")
        return jsonify({"error": "No data provided"}), 400

    if "username" not in data or "password" not in data:
        app.logger.error("Missing username or password in request")
        return jsonify({"error": "Username and password are required"}), 400

    data = request.json
    if (User.find_by_username(data["username"])):
        return jsonify("User already existed"), 409
    hashed_pw = generate_password_hash(data["password"], method='sha256')
    new_user = User(username = data["username"], password = hashed_pw)
    try:
        db.session().add(new_user)
        db.session().commit()
        app.logger.info(f"User {data['username']} registered succesfully")
        return jsonify({"message" : "Register successfully"}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"Error during user registration: {str(e)}")
        db.session.rollback()
        return jsonify({"error": "Registration Failed"})



@app.route("/login", methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.json
    user = User.find_by_username(data["username"])
    if user and check_password_hash(user.password, data["password"]):
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
        response = jsonify({"message" : "Login sucessfully"})
        set_access_cookies(response, access_token) #add cookies to the HTTP response
        return response, 200
    return jsonify({"message" : "Login Failed"}), 401

@app.route("/logout", methods=["POST"])
def logout():
    response = jsonify({"message" : "Logout succesfully"})
    unset_access_cookies(response) #BE will process all issues with authentication through cookies, on the FE we don't have to care too much
    return response, 200




models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()

#parent model
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False) #hashed password
    notes = db.relationship('Notes', backref = 'user', lazy = True, uselist = True) # set useList meaning that this is a 1-to-many relationship

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username : str):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username = username).first_or_404() #return 404 if not found username
    
    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username: str, pwd: str):
        newUser = cls(username = username, password = generate_password_hash(password=pwd))
        db.session.add(newUser)
        db.session.commit()
        return newUser

    #instance method for checking against each models
    def check_password(self, password: str):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
    

#notes model, record usage history of users
class Notes(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable = False) #title of the converstaion with AI
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable = False)

    @classmethod
    #whichever called this will need to pass the user_id of the current user who is adding
    def add_notes(cls, input_title, input_userid):
        todo = cls(title = input_title, user_id = input_userid)
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        return todo

    @classmethod
    def get_all(cls, input_userid):
        return cls.query.filter_by(user_id = input_userid).all()
    
    @classmethod
    def delete_all(cls, input_userid):
        notes_so_far = cls.query.filter_by(user_id = input_userid).all()
        for note in notes_so_far:
            db.session.delete(note)
        db.session.commit()
        print("Successfully clear the history")




The problem is that when I try to use the register route. It always return 404 Not Found.
I have tried to include some debug lines and I found out that when the "/register" route is called, the view function register() is always called. It is also able to pick up error when my HTTP Post does not contain correct data. However, when the data is correct it got the same issues.

Just in cases, there is also a problem related to a Hugging Face transformers: FutureWarning: clean_up_tokenization_spaces was not set. It will be set to True by default. This behavior will be depracted in transformers v4.45, and will be then set to False by default. For more details check this issue: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/31884 but this is unlikely related.
I uses Python version 3.11, Flask 3.0.3, and Werkzeug 3.0.3
I really appreciate any help.

How are you trying to use the /register route? Are you actually making a POST request?

Yes I was sending a POST request with username and password parameter.

After sometimes I figured out the error. I was careless because I used  first_or_404() in the User.find_by_username() method.
Since in my view register() function, it will call find_by_username() to check if the username already existed, 404 will be returned if this is a new user.
Using first() will simply solve the problem.
models.py
@classmethod
def find_by_username(cls, username : str):
   return cls.query.filter_by(username = username).first() 

Hope this may help anyone in the future.
